# How to choose what file to take when using function unzipGmail1(){ in app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to import a zipped file and choose a certain .CSV inside. How do I ask the script too search for the CSV by name and not number?

```
function unzipGmail1(){
    var threads = GmailApp.search('subject:"XXXXX"');
    var message = threads[0].getMessages();
    var blobs =  message[message.length - 1].getAttachments()[0].copyBlob();
      blobs.setContentTypeFromExtension();
    var unzippedFile = Utilities.unzip(blobs);
    var filename = unzippedFile[0].getName();
    var contentType = unzippedFile[0].getContentType();
    var csv = unzippedFile['decay vehicle list'];
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("XXXX");
   var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv();

        // Remember to clear the content of the sheet before importing new data
  sheet.getRange("A1:AO").clear();
        sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```js
 var unzippedFile = Utilities.unzip(blobs);
 var filename = unzippedFile[0].getName();
 var contentType = unzippedFile[0].getContentType();
 var csv = unzippedFile['decay vehicle list'];
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("XXXX");
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv();
```

#### To:

```js
var searchFilename = "###"; // Please set the filename you want to search.

var unzippedFile = Utilities.unzip(blobs);
var blob = unzippedFile.filter(e => e.getName() == searchFilename);
if (blob.length == 0) return;
var csv = blob[0].getDataAsString();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("XXXX");
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
```

- In this modification, the file you want to retrieve is retrieved using the filename in `blobs`. And, when the file blob of the searched filename is existing, the data is retrieved as the string value (CSV data).

#### References:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [getName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getname)
- [getDataAsString()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getdataasstring)

Comment: Hmm, I tried with this modification - in the execution logg it seems like everything worked well but once in the sheet nothing has happened. Any idea why?

Comment: @Samuel Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About your new question of `in the execution logg it seems like everything worked well but once in the sheet nothing has happened. Any idea why?`, in that case, I think that this is due to `if (blob.length == 0) return;`. The filename of `searchFilename` is not included in `blobs`. So please confirm the value of `searchFilename` and the filename of the file in `blobs` and test it again.

Comment: @Samuel For example, when you want to retrieve the filenames of the files in `blobs`, you can do it using `unzippedFile.forEach(e => console.log(e.getName()))`. In this case, please put this after the line of `var unzippedFile = Utilities.unzip(blobs);`, and run the script.

Comment: @Samuel Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `Thank you very much for the support!` and this current situation, I cannot understand whether your issue was resolved. Can I ask you whether your issue was resolved? If your issue was not resolved, I apologize and I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: It is resolved!